# How to determine whether a React component (or part of it) will be re-created?

Tags: reactjs

If we want to show/hide something inside of a React component, we can do it by one of these two ways:

```
<div className={(this.state.showPanel ? "" : "hidden")}>panel content</div>
```

(with the CSS class `hidden` being `display:none`, `visibility: hidden`, or `opacity: 0`)

or the second method:

```
{this.state.showPanel && <div>panel content</div>}
```

(are these the only two possible methods? It also seemed that the first method allow CSS transition, while the second method doesn't allow it).

Does one method run faster than the other due to re-creating the HTML element nodes?  If it is not simple content, but if there are 500 element nodes for the "panel content", and 200 nodes have no content change, while 300 nodes have content change, do the above two methods work equally fast or will method 2 involve re-creating the whole DOM fragment for the 500 nodes while method 1 doesn't?

Comment: there is performance tool in react `perf` you can use that to check this case, try this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html

Answer (score 1):

The former still places the content in the DOM, since you're only applying CSS rules to hide it. The latter ensures the `<div>` will not be included in the DOM during the next render cycle.

Either way, when you're calling `setState` to update `showPanel`, a `render` will be incurred, however it matters how much content you're inserting/removing from the DOM.

I put together this example that paints 10,000 strings to the screen, and the **CSS approach does appear to be quicker**. That said, you can pull in `react-addons-perf` to get hard numbers, but this should get you moving along.

https://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/oWjQEJ?editors=0110

[image]

Just click the buttons to toggle, and you may note a performance difference - I did on my machine.

***EDIT***: Per the comment below, I'd just like to reiterate that this is a contrived example that simply shows quick transitions with large data sets may benefit from using the CSS approach.

Comment: I would assume that keeping hundreds of unnecessary elements in the DOM has a bigger long-term performance impact due to resource usage. Using CSS might have an edge at the moment of transitioning from one state to the other. The best solution IMO would be to use ReactCSSTransitionGroup to get the best of both worlds - keep unnecessary elements out of the DOM but still be able to transition them in/out.

Comment: @jered Oh I agree, this was just a quick example to show that quick transitions with large data sets might benefit from the CSS approach.

Comment: I would say that measuring which one has better performance before even running into a performance problem is premature optimization. The only time I hit a performance problem with react was when I was building an SVG tree with about 50000 nodes and I already built some pretty big apps.

Comment: by the way, it is also just to study how it works by using different ways. The `display:none`, `visibility: hidden`, or `opacity: 0` can be used... but not all. We might try different ones, as the `visibility: hidden` might be faster, since it doesn't need to reflow the content, while `display:none` does. Again, this may just to get an understanding of it, so that a programmer can know what is going on, to make better decisions in the future